# Is there an equivalent of the ruby Fog gem for Node.js (cloud storage API)?

Tags: ruby, api, node.js, cloud

Is there a wrapper API for the main cloud services like there is for Ruby with https://github.com/fog/fog, for Node.js?

Fog is a wrapper for a lot of cloud storage API's, listed here:

- https://github.com/fog/fog/tree/master/lib/fog

Comment: is there a way to refresh this question without re-posting it?

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently an equivalent, but there is a project working in that direction.

[node-sunny](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/node-sunny)